# the right syntax to use near '? WHERE Reg = ?'

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
public static void updateData(Connection con, String make, String reg) {
    String selectString = "UPDATE Cars SET Make = ? WHERE Reg = ?";
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(selectString);
        pStmt.setString(1, make);
        pStmt.setString(2, reg);
        pStmt.executeUpdate(selectString);
        pStmt.close();

    }...
```

I am getting the following error for this piece of code:

```
SQL Exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE Reg = ?' at line 1
```

I'll appreciate if someone could help me out. I've searched around but my problem is quite different to solutions i've found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the overloaded `executeUpdate` meant for `PreparedStatements`

```
pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Yep, it worked, thanks. could I ask what was the difference between overloaded and not overloaded version?

Comment: `executeUpdate(String)` is implemented in the `Statement` class and doesnt support `PreparedStatements`. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) _This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement_